# Applying filter in DataGrid Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, filtering, mui-x-data-grid

I am trying to apply filter to the column in DataGrid. I need to get input and then set the value to filter according to it but for now I am trying to apply default filtering. I got many examples using the filterModel as same as I did but now the columnField property is not being recognized.

```
<DataGrid
          rows={rows}
          getRowId={(row) => row.txnId}
          columns={columns}
          filterModel={{
            items: [
              {
                columnField: 'vendorName',
                operatorValue: 'contains',
                value:"dd"
              }
            ]
          }}
/>
```

`Error: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'columnField' does not exist in type 'GridFilterItem'.ts(2353)`

Answer (score 0):

I found out that  newer version of material ui have property

```
{
  field: 'vendorName',
  operator: 'contains',
  value:"dd"
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).